# Using OpenVV to detect ad impressions

Tags: video, jwplayer, ads

I'm trying to use the [OpenVV](https://github.com/InteractiveAdvertisingBureau/openvv) to detect valid ad impressions. 
I read the git documentation but i cant seem to find a simple example how to integrate it into my HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really have any experience with openvv but I know that the JW Player itself can detect when an ad impression has fired using our JS API - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413089-javascript-api-reference,

```
.on('adImpression')
```

VAST and IMA. Fired based on the IAB definition of an ad impression. This occurs the instant a video ad begins to play. Event attributes:

tag (String): The ad tag that is currently playing.

creativetype (String): The type of ad that is being played.

adposition (String): Defines if an ad called in a pre, mid, or post position

Comment: I am actually using it in my code, but it is not enough for what i am trying to accomplish.
The ad providers (Live Rail, Spot X ...) pay you for an ad impression only when the following terms are met:
1. Ad is played for at least 2 seconds.
2. During the 2 seconds at least 50% of the ad was displayed, meaning not below the fold or hidden from the user.

Comment: Maybe you can use a JS setTimeOut and see if it has taken more than 2 seconds on AdImpression?